# Updating input data MatLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, import-from-excel

I have got a GUI, which imports the data from a *.xls file and plots graph. The last thing I cannot do is the data refreshing, because my xls file updates each 15 sec. I want my GUI to update input data each 20 seconds. How can I do that? And also I would like to have a button which will have an ability to pause/run data updating.

```
    function viewSTUEP
global hPlot hChoice raw
  handles.F = figure('Name','viewSTUEP', 'Position',[100 20 900 550], ...
    'Color',[0.8 0.8 0.8], 'NumberTitle','off', 'Resize','off');
   uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'Position',[690 510 94 30], ...
    'FontSize',12, 'String','Load', 'Callback',@LoadData);
   uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'Position',[790 510 94 30], ...
    'FontSize',12, 'String','Save plot', 'Callback',@SaveAs);
  uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'Position', [690 475 94 30], ...
    'FontSize',12, 'String','Update', 'Callback',@UpdatePlot);
  uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'Position',[790 475 94 30], ...
    'FontSize',12, 'String','Close', 'Callback',{@Close,handles});
  set(handles.F, 'CloseRequestFcn', {@Close,handles})
  set(gcf, 'Toolbar', 'figure');
  clear raw, raw(1,:) = {''};
  hPlot = axes('Position',[0.06 0.08 0.68 0.9], 'Visible','on');
  uicontrol('Style','text', 'Position',[690 432 130 35], ...
    'BackgroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8], 'FontSize',12, ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','left', 'String','Columns for plot:');
  hChoice = uicontrol('Style','listbox', 'Position',[690 420 204 22], ...
    'FontSize',12, 'String',raw(1,:), 'Min',1, 'Max',1);

function Close(hObject, eventdata, handles)
delete(handles.F);

function LoadData(hObject, eventdata)
global hChoice raw xdat
  [fname, pname] = uigetfile('*.xls','Select a data file');
  if fname ~= 0
    filename = strcat(pname, fname);
    [numeric,text,raw] = xlsread(filename);
    num = length(raw(1,:));
    if (num > 21) num = 21; end
    posY = 442 - (20*num);
    set(hChoice, 'String',raw(1,:));
    set(hChoice, 'Max',num);
    set(hChoice, 'Position',[690 posY 204 (20*num)]);
    xdat = datenum(0,0,0,0,0,cell2mat(raw(2:end,6)));
  end

function UpdatePlot(hObject, eventdata)
global hPlot hChoice raw xdat
  if ~isempty(raw)
    cols = get(hChoice,'Value'); 
    plot(hPlot, xdat,cell2mat(raw(2:end,cols(1))), 'LineWidth',2), datetick('x','HH:MM')
    grid on
    if (length(cols) > 1)
      colors = 'brgcmyk'; c = 2;
      hold(hPlot, 'on')
      for k = cols(2:end)
        plot(hPlot, xdat,cell2mat(raw(2:end,k)),colors(c),'LineWidth',2)
        c = c+1; if (c > 7) c = 1; end
      end
      hold(hPlot, 'off')
    end
    legend(hPlot, raw(1,cols), 'Interpreter','none','Location','SouthEast')
    xlabel(hPlot, 'Time in minutes:');
    ylabel(hPlot, 'Temperature in C:');
  end 

 function SaveAs(hObject, eventdata, handles)
         [Save,savename] = uiputfile('*.eps','Save plot as: ')
         fname=fullfile(savename,Save);
         print('-depsc','-r300','-noui',fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a timer object - [see here](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f9-38055.html)

Comment: I know about that I need timer object, but I don't know how to use this feature, thus I didn't ever used it( For that I am asking the help of someone who can help me to understand an do this...

Comment: Then I suppose you read the link and tried the example code. Please update your question and show us where you have problems.